# Using PHP checkbox array with GET Method

Tags: php, arrays, forms, checkbox

Can I use PHP `checkbox` array with the GET Method?
And if there are two checkboxes clicked, will that result in: some.php?param=1&param=2 ?

As you know, I am not used to write into database, I'm just getting the parameters. Thanks.

Comment: hi, how are you able to convert checkbox which i think is usually inside a form into a GET format?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to pass the checkboxes with the same field name followed by `[]` so PHP recognizes the array.

Like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="bar1">
<input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="bar2">
<input type="checkbox" name="foo[]" value="bar3">
```

So the GET would be:

```
phpfile.php?foo[]=bar1&foo[]=bar2&foo[]=bar3
```

if every checkbox is clicked. (POST similar)

Please note, that only the clicked checkboxes will be submitted. So, if just `bar1` and `bar2` are clicked, then the GET would be

```
phpfile.php?foo[]=bar1&foo[]=bar2
```

Then you can access that array via

```
$_GET["foo"]
```

or similar to POST

```
$_POST["foo"]
```

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: Now, can you tel me howto make it into variable?
Example : I have foo checkbox array and I want the value is being included into one variable. Thanks

Comment: sorry, i really don't understand your question :( you mean [implode](http://www.php.net/implode) to merge the array into one string?

Comment: If you see `%5B` and `%5D` in the URL it's just Unicode for `[` and `]`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what steve said, you could also add certain keys if you'd like to:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="foo[my_id_1]" value="bar1">
<input type="checkbox" name="foo[my_id_2]" value="bar2">
<input type="checkbox" name="foo[my_id_3]" value="bar3">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
some.php?param[]=1&param[key]=2
```

Answer (score 0):

Let be the checkbox names are aa and values are 1 and 2 respectively .Put the form method as GET and the checkbox names are aa[0],aa[1] . when you submit the form, the data will pass in url like some.php?aa[0]=1&aa[1]=2